# PHP - Class not found fatal error

Tags: php, model-view-controller, classnotfoundexception

I am creating a custom MVC framework in PHP based on the [tutorial by Anant Garg](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/):

```
CustomMVC
-app
    --controllers
        ---Controller.php
        ---HomeController.php   
    --models
        ---Home.php
    --views
-config
    --app.php
-lib
    --bootstrap.php
    --shared.php
    --database.class.php
-public
    --.htaccess
    --index.php
-tmp
-.htaccess
```

My HomeController cannot extend the Controller and I get the following:

> Fatal error: Class 'app\controllers\Controller' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CustomMVC/app/controllers/homecontroller.php
>   on line 7

Both of them are under the same namespace and they are located under the same directory. I don't know why HomeController cannot extend the base Controller. Any advice on that?

> namespace app\controllers;

**Controller.php**

```
namespace app\controllers;

use lib\Template;

class Controller {

    protected $_model;
    protected $_controller;
    protected $_action;
    protected $_template;

    public function __construct($model, $controller, $action) {

        $this->_controller = $controller;
        $this->_action = $action;
        $this->_model = $model;

        $this->_model =& new $model;
        $this->_template =& new Template($controller,$action);

    }

    function set($name,$value) {
        $this->_template->set($name,$value);
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->_template->render();
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    function getHome($id = null,$name = null) {

    }

    function getAbout() {

    }

    function postContact() {

    }
}
```

This is the autoload function in the lib**shared.php**

```
function __autoload($className) {

    if ( file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'lib' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php') )
    {
        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'lib' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
    }
    else if ( file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'lib' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php'))
    {
        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'lib' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php');
    }
    else if ( file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'controllers' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php'))
    {
        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'controllers' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
    }
    else if( file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'controllers' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php'))
    {
        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'controllers' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php');
    }
    else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'models' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php'))
    {
        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'models' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.php');
    }
    else if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'models' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php'))
    {
        require_once(ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'models' . DS . strtolower($className) . '.class.php');
    }
    else
    {
        /* Error Generation Code Here */
    }
}
```

Comment: `use app\controllers;` isn't the correct usage of `use`.  Honestly, while  that tutorial may give you some good starting points, it is outdated and that autoloader looks like junk as far as efficiency goes.  Look into the PSR standard autoloader designs or just use Composer.

Comment: your HomeController.php file should be homecontroller.php (in lowercase)